# How do I determine if 3 points fall on a straight line?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, slope

$1.\;A(0,0,0),\,B(9,−4,3),\,C(−36,16,−12)\\ 
2.\;D(9,−4,3),\,E(10,−2,6),\,F(14,6,18)\\ 
3.\;G(−1,0,1),\,H(3,9,10),\,I(8,27,28)$

I want to determine if these points fall on a straight line.

From my method 1 does, but 2 and 3 don't. But I am not sure if I am doing it right. What I did is find AB, then BC and see that its the same slope.

Comment: I think $2.$ does too.  How did you define slope in $3$d?

Comment: Given any 3 points/vectors $u,v,w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. They are colinear if and only if following cross product vanishes $$(u - v)\times(u - w) = u\times v + v \times w + w\times u = 0$$ If you compute this cross product for the 3 cases, you will find case 1. and 2. are colinear while case 3. isn't.

Comment: What is this mysterious method that you’re using?

Answer (score 2):

Pick one point, say $A$ then form $B-A$, $C-A$ and check that they are multiples of each other.

I get $(C-A) = -4(B-A)$ so they are on a straight line.

I get $(F-D) = 5(E-D)$ so they are on a straight line.

$I-G$ is not a multiple of $H-G$ so they are not colinear.

Comment: I like this answer because it generalizes easily to any number of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these three points as a triangle.
What would be its area, if they are collinear?